# how do i clear the error icons in c# tabpage?

Tags: c#, winforms

Ive been researching and trying for the past 5 hours to clear the error icons from the required fields (city, state, country, longitude, and latitude) that appear to the right side of each textbox if the user does not enter stuff in them.

its all good and well except the fact once the create button displays the entry created message, and I click ok, the fields reset and all, but all 5 error icons appear next to them.

how can I get the tab page to kind of reload after the message ok is clicked so that these error icons would stop appearing after the message confirmation?

only when I close and reload the whole form the icons aren't there. I don't wanna keep redoing that for them to not appear initially!

here is part of the code that is associated with what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
private void createEntryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*//if required boxes are left empty, reveal error
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(createCityTextBox.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(createStateTextBox.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(createCountryTextBox.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(createLongitudeTextBox.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(createLatitudeTextBox.Text))
    {
        cityError.SetError(createCityTextBox, "City field is empty!");
        stateError.SetError(createStateTextBox, "State field is empty!");
        countryError.SetError(createCountryTextBox, "Country field is empty!");
        longitudeError.SetError(createLongitudeTextBox, "Longitude field is empty!");
        latitudeError.SetError(createLatitudeTextBox, "Latitude field is empty!");
    }
    */

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(createCityTextBox.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(createStateTextBox.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(createCountryTextBox.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(createLongitudeTextBox.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(createLatitudeTextBox.Text))
    {
        //cityError.Clear();
        //stateError.Clear();
        //countryError.Clear();
        //longitudeError.Clear();
        //latitudeError.Clear();

        MessageBox.Show("New entry created!");

        //resetting the fields
        foreach (Control item in createEntryTab.Controls)
        {
            if (item is TextBox)
            {
                item.Text = "";
            }

        }//end foreach
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(createCityTextBox.Text))
        {
            cityError.SetError(createCityTextBox, "City field is empty!");
        }
        else
        {
            cityError.Clear();
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(createStateTextBox.Text))
        {
            stateError.SetError(createStateTextBox, "State field is empty!");
        }
        else
        {
            stateError.Clear();
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(createCountryTextBox.Text))
        {
            countryError.SetError(createCountryTextBox, "Country field is empty!");
        }
        else
        {
            countryError.Clear();
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(createLongitudeTextBox.Text))
        {
            longitudeError.SetError(createLongitudeTextBox, "Longitude field is empty!");
        }
        else
        {
            longitudeError.Clear();
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(createLatitudeTextBox.Text))
        {
            latitudeError.SetError(createLatitudeTextBox, "Latitude field is empty!");
        }
        else
        {
            latitudeError.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: winforms / wpf ? add proper tag plz.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan yup forms...added the tag

Comment: Use only one ErrorProvider, it can display a warning on any control.  Use SetError(control, "") to hide the warning.  Its Clear() method then removes all warnings.

Comment: Hans, I tried that alrdy initially but it didn't work